# What version of Node does my library support?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm hoping for a library or a tool which will run through my code and tell me what version of Node is required in order to run it. Perhaps better would be it alerts me to areas of the code which could be changed to support older versions.

Is there anything like that in the wild?

Comment: I don't think it exists usually you can use package.json to lock the node engine and not worry about what is supported on different versions. imho choose recent LTS versions or use polyfills if something is found missing.

Comment: Quoting from the Help Center: ***Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.***

Comment: I built a library and would like to optimise it to work in a broader number of environments. I searched online for a resource and didn't find any so I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this exactly what you are looking for, but [there is an existing `package.json` property called "engines"](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) where package developers can specify what version(s) they require. Not too difficult to use `glob` and `semver` packages to look through all package.json files with an "engines" requirement and compile that into an object of:

```
{ 
  [version1]: [{ packageName, currentlySupported }, { ... }],
  [version2]: [...],
  ...
}
```

Here is a rudimentary example of a script which will create that object for you:

```
npm install glob semver
```

checkversions.js:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');
const semver = require('semver');
const currentVersion = process.version;
const versions = {};

glob('node_modules/*/package.json', (err, files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
        const pkg = require(path.resolve(__dirname, file));
        // only check add package if it specifies "engines"
        if (pkg.engines && pkg.engines.node) {
            const reqdVersion = pkg.engines.node.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            // assume you are using a supported version
            let currentlySupported = true;
            // check if current node version satisfies package requirements
            if (!semver.satisfies(currentVersion, reqdVersion)) {
                currentlySupported = false;
            }

            if (!Array.isArray(versions[reqdVersion])) {
                versions[reqdVersion] = [];
            }

            versions[reqdVersion].push({
                package: file.replace(/node_modules\/(.*)\/package.json/, '$1'),
                currentlySupported,
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(versions);
});
```

Run it:

```
node checkversions.js
```